# The SQL provider cannot run because of a missing dependency. Please make sure that Microsoft SQL Server Transact-SQL ScriptDom is installed

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, web-publishing, scriptdom

Web deployment task failed.
 (The SQL provider cannot run because of a missing dependency. Please make sure that Microsoft SQL Server Transact-SQL ScriptDom is installed.

I get this error while publishing any web app in visual studio with update database enabled. It was working fine until I upgraded SQL SERVER MANAGEMENT Studio to 2016.
 I tried unistalling and reinstalling sql server and all required components but in vain
Any suggestions will be appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Registering the ScriptDom assembly in the GAC solved this for us:

```
"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.2 Tools\gacutil" /i "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\DAC\130\Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom.dll
```

Comment: I don't have a SQLDB folder. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

I had to

Use Web Platform Installer to install:

1. Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Data-Tier Application Framework
2. SQL Server 2012 Transact-SQL ScriptDom
3. SQL Server System CLR Types 11.0

AND register it myself (adjusting for version numbers)

```
"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.2 Tools\gacutil" /i "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\DAC\130\Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom.dll
```

Comment: I installed the stuff and it still wasn't working, doing the registration is what finally did it for me

Comment: For Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise: "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.2 Tools\gacutil" /i "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\DAC\140\Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom.dll"

Answer (score 1):

- DacFxNeededForSQLProvider
- ERROR_SCRIPTDOM_NEEDED_FOR_SQL_PROVIDER
- ERROR_SQLCLRTYPES_NEEDED_FOR_SQL_PROVIDER

The group of 3 errors listed above share the following diagnosis and resolution:

*Diagnosis:* SQL DAC and its dependencies are not installed

*Resolution:* Use Web Platform Installer to install:

1. Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Data-Tier Application Framework
2. SQL Server 2012 Transact-SQL ScriptDom
3. SQL Server System CLR Types 11.0

[source](https://www.iis.net/learn/publish/troubleshooting-web-deploy/web-deploy-error-codes#ERROR_SCRIPTDOM_NEEDED_FOR_SQL_PROVIDER)

Comment: I installed all of these but no luck

Answer (score 1):

Installing the SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) package for Visual Studio 2012 resolved the error for me.

You can download the installer for VS2012 and VS2013 from here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674919.aspx#Anchor_0

Comment: SSDT requires visual studio i cant install visual studio on server

Comment: SSDT is required on your client machine/desktop where you are publishing from

Comment: I have SSDT 14.0.6519 installed on dev pc.It publishes to other servers just not this one.

Answer (score 1):

Run below code in command prompt, it works.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.2 Tools\gacutil" /i "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\DAC\130\Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom.dll"
```

[click here for source](https://github.com/appveyor/ci/issues/977)

Answer (score 0):

**Registering all of these dll to gac works for me.**
Write all of these command to command prompt. Make sure to open cmd as "Administrator"

`"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools\gacutil" /i "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DAC\bin\Hyak.Common.dll
"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools\gacutil" /i "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DAC\bin\Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.dll
"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools\gacutil" /i "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DAC\bin\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Utilities.dll
"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools\gacutil" /i "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DAC\bin\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.Platform.dll
"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools\gacutil" /i "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DAC\bin\Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.Extensions.dll
"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools\gacutil" /i "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DAC\bin\Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.dll
"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools\gacutil" /i "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DAC\bin\Microsoft.Azure.Common.dll
"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools\gacutil" /i "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DAC\bin\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.dll
"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools\gacutil" /i "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DAC\bin\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.dll
"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools\gacutil" /i "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DAC\bin\Microsoft.SqlServer.DacAzureExtensions.dll
"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools\gacutil" /i "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DAC\bin\Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.AlwaysEncrypted.AzureKeyVaultProvider.dll
"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools\gacutil" /i "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DAC\bin\Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll
"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools\gacutil" /i "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DAC\bin\Extensions\Microsoft.SqlServer.Services.ImportExport.DacFxExtensions.dll`